# How to get the target Python package directory in a custom setup.py step?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

In the setup.py file of my pip package I have a custom step:

```
    cmdclass={'install': InstallExtraData},
```

This step is supposed to install custom data files into my Python package. In other words: I'm not trying to write outside of the package, but I also don't want to include these files into the pip package as data_files (they should be downloaded from a different location).
My custom step currently looks like this:

```
from setuptools.command.install import install

class InstallExtraData(install):
    def _install_extra_data(self, target_package_dir):
        pass

    def run(self):
        super(InstallExtraData, self).run()
        target_package_dir = "???"  # TODO
        self._install_extra_data(target_package_dir)
```

How do I find out the value for target_package_dir?

Answer (score 0):

```
target_package_dir = os.path.join(self.install_lib, "name_of_the_package_here")
```